# Understanding swift code tuple compound in a function

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

I just started learning swift from "The Swift Programming Language(Swift 3 beta)". I came across a function that has tuple return type. They have not fully explained it. Here func "calculateStatistics" takes in "score" array of Int type and it has tuple compound as a return type. Now in the end when they call it with print statement, I do not understand, what is meant by  "print (statistics.2)" statement. What ".2" means and how it is calculated.

```
func calculateStatistics(scores : [Int]) -> (min: Int , max: Int , sum: Int)
{

var min = scores[0]
var max = scores[0]
var sum = 0

    for score in scores {

        if score > max
        {
            max = score
        }else if score < min{

            min = score
        }

        sum += score

    }

return (min, max, sum)

}

let statistics = calculateStatistics([5 , 3, 100, 3, 9])

print (statistics.sum)
print (statistics.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tuple is similar to a simple struct, in that example you have a "struct" with 3 elements and with `statistics.2` they are referring to the 3rd element of the tuple, sum (index starting from 0).

Since that function also defines a name for the individual elements,  `statistic.sum` works too.

Answer (score -1):

a tuple in swift as a comma-separated list of types enclosed in parentheses and is commonly used t return multiple values. we can get results in return with dot notation. it is known as the mashup of the javascript object and arrays, for example, foo= (0, int, bool). the function is run and on the sum, it will always run and add up the values and max-min values not showing because the only sum is getting. min is 3 and max is 100. on index 2 we get 100. and sum will be 108